# parse, expected string, but got number in cloud function?

Tags: parse-platform

I am in a cloud function in parse. From an iOS client I send up a NSDictionary that contains parameters the cloud function needs. One of these I send up as a NSNumber. It's an age value. So, in the cloud function I create an object "A" like so:

```
var A = Parse.Object.extend("A");
var a = new A();
```

I then set the age like this:

```
a.set("age",ageParam);
```

ageParam comes from this:

```
var ageParam = request.params.age;
```

When I run the function from the iOS client the server returns this error:

**`expected string, but got number, code=141`**

So, I am not sure how to put a number in there instead of a string since I do want to pass up a number since it's an age...

How can I solve this correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was going on. When I was saving "a" for the first time ever in the parse database it worked. From then on it would return the error above.

It looks like parse was handling converting the string (age) right before saving into the database. So then the subsequent saves would return this error because I would try to pass in a string instead of a number.

I solved it by using parseInt, this fixed my problem:

var ageParam = parseInt(request.params.age);